# Python dict group and sum multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, sum, grouping

I have a set of data in the list of dict format like below:

```
data = [
    {'name': 'A', 'tea':5, 'coffee':6},
    {'name': 'A', 'tea':2, 'coffee':3},
    {'name': 'B', 'tea':7, 'coffee':1},
    {'name': 'B', 'tea':9, 'coffee':4},
]
```

I'm trying to group by 'name' and sum the 'tea' separately and 'coffee' separately

The final grouped data must be in the this format:

```
grouped_data = [
    {'name': 'A', 'tea':7, 'coffee':9},
    {'name': 'B', 'tea':16, 'coffee':5},
]
```

I tried some steps:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter()
for v in data:
    c[v['name']] += v['tea']

my_data = [{'name': name, 'tea':tea} for name, tea in c.items()]
for e in my_data:
    print e
```

The above step returned the following output:

```
{'name': 'A', 'tea':7,}
{'name': 'B', 'tea':16}
```

Only I can sum the key 'tea', I'm not able to get the sum for the key 'coffee', can you guys please help to solve this solution to get the grouped_data format

Comment: Why are you using a `Counter`? Why not just use a dictionary?

Comment: Look at `zip` function https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: @blacksite Thanks for your response , I just tried with that, but I cant get the solution

Comment: Do you use pandas? It's only a couple of lines.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I tried with pandas, but I am not able to convert the datafarame to dict format that I am expecting

Comment: @AjayKumar See answer, use `df.to_dict`.

Comment: @AjayKumar if you're at all curious I created a function without imports

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `pandas`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df

   coffee name  tea
0       6    A    5
1       3    A    2
2       1    B    7
3       4    B    9


g = df.groupby('name', as_index=False).sum()
g

  name  coffee  tea
0    A       9    7
1    B       5   16
```

And, the final step, `df.to_dict`:

```
d = g.to_dict('r')

d
[{'coffee': 9, 'name': 'A', 'tea': 7}, {'coffee': 5, 'name': 'B', 'tea': 16}]
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED , thank you so much for your answered, I missed the 'as_index=False'  in my code, it works well.

Comment: Damn... Was *thisclose* to that same result, but forgot about `as_index`!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
data = [
{'name': 'A', 'tea':5, 'coffee':6},
{'name': 'A', 'tea':2, 'coffee':3},
{'name': 'B', 'tea':7, 'coffee':1},
{'name': 'B', 'tea':9, 'coffee':4},
]
import itertools
final_data = [(a, list(b)) for a, b in itertools.groupby([i.items() for i in data], key=lambda x:dict(x)["name"])] 
new_final_data = [{i[0][0]:sum(c[-1] for c in i if isinstance(c[-1], int)) if i[0][0] != "name" else i[0][-1] for i in zip(*b)} for a, b in final_data]
```

Output:

```
[{'tea': 7, 'coffee': 9, 'name': 'A'}, {'tea': 16, 'coffee': 5, 'name': 'B'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pandas, this is pretty easy to do:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {'name': 'A', 'tea':5, 'coffee':6},
    {'name': 'A', 'tea':2, 'coffee':3},
    {'name': 'B', 'tea':7, 'coffee':1},
    {'name': 'B', 'tea':9, 'coffee':4},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.groupby(['name']).sum()

      coffee  tea
name             
A          9    7
B          5   16
```

Here's one way to get it into your dict format:

```
grouped_data = []
for idx in gb.index:
    d = {'name': idx}
    d = {**d, **{col: gb.loc[idx, col] for col in gb}}
    grouped_data.append(d)


grouped_data
Out[15]: [{'coffee': 9, 'name': 'A', 'tea': 7}, {'coffee': 5, 'name': 'B', 'tea': 16}]
```

But COLDSPEED got the native pandas solution with the `as_index=False` config...

Comment: Thanks for your response , I too tried with pandas and came till this, but I am not able to convert the datafarame to dict format that I am expecting

Comment: thanks this solutions also works

Answer (score 1):

[Click here to see snap shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOkzx.png)

`import pandas as pd
df =  pd.DataFrame(data)
df2=df.groupby('name').sum()
df2.to_dict('r')`

Comment: @karthick reddy, Thanks I too tried these steps, but I am not able to convert the datafarame to dict format that I am expecting, now I got solution.

Comment: Your welcome!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method I created, you can input the key you want to group by:

```
def group_sum(key,list_of_dicts):
    d = {}
    for dct in list_of_dicts:
        if dct[key] not in d:
            d[dct[key]] = {}
        for k,v in dct.items():
            if k != key:
                if k not in d[dct[key]]:
                    d[dct[key]][k] = v
                else:
                    d[dct[key]][k] += v
    final_list = []
    for k,v in d.items():
        temp_d = {key: k}
        for k2,v2 in v.items():
            temp_d[k2] = v2
        final_list.append(temp_d)
    return final_list


data = [
    {'name': 'A', 'tea':5, 'coffee':6},
    {'name': 'A', 'tea':2, 'coffee':3},
    {'name': 'B', 'tea':7, 'coffee':1},
    {'name': 'B', 'tea':9, 'coffee':4},
]

grouped_data = group_sum("name",data)
print (grouped_data)
```

result:

```
[{'coffee': 5, 'name': 'B', 'tea': 16}, {'coffee': 9, 'name': 'A', 'tea': 7}]
```

I guess this would be slower when summing thousands of dicts compared to pandas, maybe not, I don't know. It also doesn't seem to maintain order unless you use ordereddict or python 3.6