# printing sum of same values from a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using for loop to go through the list like:

```
for c in classes:
    print(c.get(‘class’), c.get('plan'), c.get('type'), c.get(‘money’,{})[0].get(‘totalspent’))
```

I get results:

```
class1   plan1  type1 10
class2   plan2  type2 20
class3   plan3  type3 10
class2   plan2  type2 30
class3   plan3  type3 20
```

I am trying to figure out a way to get something like:

```
class1  plan1 type1 10
class2  plan2 type2 50
class3  plan3 type3 30
```

is there an easier way to achieve this?

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055259/python-dict-group-and-sum-multiple-values

Answer (score -1):

Just figured it as soon as I made a post. Maybe will help someone else in the future:

from collections import defaultdict

```
output = defaultdict(int)

for c in classes:
    output[c.get('class'), c.get('plan'), c.get('type')] += c.get('money', {})[0].get('totalspent', 0)
```